# Upgrading H2 database gives constraint not found exception

Tags: sql, migration, h2

I am trying to upgrade my H2 dependency which I use on my testcases from `1.4.200` to `2.1.212` but it gives a constraint not found exception when I try to do so. The SQL is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE itineraries
(
  id SERIAL,
  itinerary_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  user_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  version INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  update_timestamp BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT itineraries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (itinerary_id, user_id),
  CONSTRAINT itineraries_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX itineraries_id_key ON itineraries (id);

CREATE TABLE subscriptions
(
  subscription_id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(20),
  last_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  itinerary_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  itinerary_db_id BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT subscriptions_it_itinerary_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (itinerary_db_id) REFERENCES itineraries (id)
);
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found; SQL statement:
```

What needs to be changed about the SQL? Since to me it seems like the unique index is created before the create table query.

Answer (score 0):

Unique indexes and unique constraints are different things.

You need to create a constraint and you don't need an index in H2, because unique constraints in H2 create indexes automatically.

```sql
CREATE TABLE itineraries
(
  id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY CONSTRAINT itineraries_id_key UNIQUE,
  …
```

I changed PostgreSQL-compatibility `SERIAL` to standard-compliant `BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`, because `SERIAL` is a legacy data type and it creates an `INTEGER` column, but it is referenced by `subscriptions.itinerary_db_id` with `BIGINT` data type, it isn't strictly required, but normally you should use the same data type for both columns, you can choose `BIGINT`, `INTEGER` or some other numeric type.

Usually it is more reasonable to create a primary key constraint for `id` column and a unique constraint for `(itinerary_id, user_id)`, but you may have own reasons for such schema.

Also `VARCHAR(36)` looks like a some data type for UUID values, H2 has more efficient specialized `UUID` data type for this purpose.